# What is the difference between: "I had eaten X before I ate...: and "I had eaten X when I ate..."

Tags: tense, time

what is the difference between :

1. I had eaten a pound of chocolate before I ate my dinner.
2. I had eaten a pound of chocolate when I ate my dinner.

Comment: I don't think we would say it as in Q2. Can you provide the context in which it appears?

Comment: If you add "already" to #2 it becomes OK.  "I had already eaten a pound...when"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the past perfect tense (had eaten) when a past action occurs before (or leads up to) another  past action.  Therefore, #1 is correct.  It means you ate chocolate in the past, but you ate it *before* you ate dinner (also in the past).

@Crosby is correct in saying we would not say #2.  This is because the verb tense is not correct.  The past perfect tense is not often used with the word *when*.  When *when* means "at the same time" or "while," the sentence typically requires the simple past ...

> I ate a pound of chocolate when I ate my dinner.

The above sentence is only for example purposes.  A better way to phrase this would be...

> I ate a pound of chocolate during dinner.

Or

> I ate a pound of chocolate at dinner time.

Either way, the action was occurring *at the same time* or *while* you were eating dinner.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your advice is upside down. We often *don't* use the past perfect when the sequence of events is already clear because of prepositions like *before* or *after*. So in number (1) we do not need to use the past perfect at all. We could just use the past simple: *I ate a pound of chocolate before I ate my dinner*. In the second sentence, where it would be unclear which happened first, the chocolate or the dinner, the past perfect is appropriate-assuming that the chocolate eating happened before the dinner did. So *I had eaten a pound of chocolate when I ate my dinner* would be ok in this context.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is two-fold; there is a correct way of using the past perfect tense, and you probably shouldn't use the past perfect tense, unless you're writing an uneducated fictional character.

If you want your characters to sound like country bumpkins you can have them say something like,

"You see that guy over there? About a week ago he punched me in the stomach, thinking I was someone else and I puked green all over his shirt; You see, I **had eaten** a whole bowl of Jello earlier in the day..."

Unless you're writing fictional characters, keep this garbage out of your writing. If you have two past tense indicators you need to remove one. The above character sketch could just as easily been written as:

"You see, earlier that day I **had** a whole bowl of Jello..."

or

"You see, earlier that day I **ate** a whole bowl of Jello..."